# ASP.Net Core RC1: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

`Please note: As the answer shows this problem is specific for ASP.Net Core Release Candidate 1.`

In ASP.Net Core / MVC 6 accessing the URL http://localhost:58000/Admin/RebuildIndex/AspNetUserRoles/PK_IdentityUserRole%3Cstring%3E

Gives this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
>      at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean
>   checkAdditional)
>      at System.IO.Path.GetExtension(String path)
>      at  Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.TryGetContentType(String subpath, String& contentType)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.StaticFileContext.LookupContentType()
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()

This is due to the < and > characters in the URL. If I access a different page such as http://localhost:58000/Admin/RebuildIndex/AspNetRoles/RoleNameIndex then it works fine.

My route is this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    // Area route
    routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

    // Default route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

And the controller I am accessing looks like this:

```
[Route("Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [Route("RebuildIndex/{tableName}/{indexName}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RebuildIndex(string tableName, string indexName)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In previous versions of ASP.Net we used the [httpRuntime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx) tag in Web.Config to relax things when we got the "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)" error. So I have tried the following (and some variants of it) in web.config without success:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
  </system.web>
```

However looking at the error message this error seems to be because the request is handled as a static file instead of being given to a MVC Controller.

How is this solved in ASP.Net Core?
It would be nice with a solution to allow it only for a particular route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue already logged and fixed for **RC2** (Which should be released on February 2016, according to [the roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap)).

- Check the [issue 82](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/issues/84) of the AspNet.StaticFiles repo.

In case you wonder, you can check the latest version of the [`FileExtensionContentTypeProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs#L440) class. You will see that `TryGetExtension` no longer uses `System.IO.Path.GetExtension` (They even added a comment you will find quite interesting!):

```
public bool TryGetContentType(string subpath, out string contentType)
{
    string extension = GetExtension(subpath);
    if (extension == null)
    {
        contentType = null;
        return false;
    }
    return Mappings.TryGetValue(extension, out contentType);
}

private static string GetExtension(string path)
{
    // Don't use Path.GetExtension as that may throw an exception if there are
    // invalid characters in the path. Invalid characters should be handled
    // by the FileProviders

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
    {
        return null;
    }

    int index = path.LastIndexOf('.');
    if (index < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return path.Substring(index);
}
```

So I guess you can either wait for RC2 to be released or use your local clone of the [StaticFiles](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles) repo.

Comment: Thank you. Added "RC1" to the title since this Q&A is specific to RC1. I'll wait for RC2.